# jQuery Form Submit in IE8 posting to new page instead of preventing it

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#data_form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("it submits");
});
```

When I submit the form in Chrome it works fine but not in IE8. I tried to change the code to something like this:

```
jQuery("#data_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("it submits");
});
```

This however still posts the page. Any idea on how to make this code work in IE8?

***EDIT: I tried to simplify the code for readability on here. However I tried the answer below and it didn't work yet. Here is the complete code:

```
jQuery("#event_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#results").html('');
    already_submitted = jQuery("#check_submission").val();
    create_yes_no = jQuery("#create_yes_no").val();
    if(already_submitted!="yes" && create_yes_no=="yes" ){
    jQuery.post(site_url + "save_event_form.php", jQuery(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            var results = jQuery("#results");
            results.html(data+"<br><br>");

            results.show(); // re-display the div
            setTimeout(function(){ // then fade it out....
              results.fadeOut();
            }, 5000); // ...after 5 seconds
            jQuery("#check_submission").val("yes");
        });
    }else if(create_yes_no!="yes"){
    jQuery.post(site_url + "save_event_form.php", jQuery(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded in the create yes or no yes: " + data);
            var results = jQuery("#results");
            results.html(data+"<br><br>");

            results.show(); // re-display the div
            setTimeout(function(){ // then fade it out....
              results.fadeOut();
            }, 5000); // ...after 5 seconds
        });
    }else{
        alert("You already submitted this user once. Refresh the page to add another one.");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is a JS error on the page. Did you check for any errors during page load or using the error console?

Comment: Also I'm using jQuery instead of $ because I'm in Wordpress and the no conflict was an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.preventDefault doesn't work in IE8. I changed it to be this code and it works good now:

```
if(event.preventDefault){
    event.preventDefault();
}else{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```